# Writing files using multiprocessing and pandas doesn't gve right result

Tags: python, file, pandas, multiprocessing

### Overview:

I'm trying to use multiprocessing and pandas. The idea is that I have large file that I can't fit into memory, and I need to to some data manipulation on it and produce N number of files. Where N is the number of cores (for me it's `8`).

### What is working:

If I'm not using `multiprocessing` everything works fine. And line numbers are the same from original file and all output files alltogeter:

```
111013 litle_dd.csv
```

and output:

```
root@xxxx:/tmp/tmpXw_KKV$ wc -l *
   14000 part_0
   14000 part_1
   14000 part_2
   14000 part_3
   14000 part_4
   14000 part_5
   14000 part_6
   13011 part_7
  111011 total
```

Two lines are actually - header and the one I'm skipping with `skiprows=[1]`

### What is not working

```
root@xxxxxx:/tmp/tmpd7GcYP$ wc -l *
   112000 part_0
   112000 part_1
   112000 part_2
   112000 part_3
   112000 part_4
   112000 part_5
   112000 part_6
   104088 part_7
   888088 total
```

As you can see line numbers are a lot more (I assume it depends on the number of cores - 8)

### Code

```
import sys                                                                      
import os                                                                       
import multiprocessing as mp                                                    
import Queue                                                                    
import subprocess                                                               
import tempfile                                                                 
import csv                                                                      
import logging                                                                  
                                                                                
import pandas as pd                                                             
                                                                                
                                                                                
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,                                        
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')              
log = logging.getLogger('converter')                                            
                                                                                
if len(sys.argv) != 3:                                                          
    raise Exception("Need more arguments")                                      
                                                                                
                                                                                
queue = Queue.Queue()                                                           
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())                                                  
                                                                                
file_path = sys.argv[1]                                                         
enc = sys.argv[2]                                                               
                                                                                
temp_folder = tempfile.mkdtemp()                                                
workers = []                                                                    
                                                                                
def write_to_file():                                                            
    while True:                                                                 
        try:                                                                    
            df, name = queue.get(False)                                         
            df.to_csv(name, index_label=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, mode='a', 
                      header=False)                                             
            queue.task_done()                                                   
            log.debug(queue.qsize())                                            
        except Queue.Empty:                                                     
            log.info('No more items for this process')                          
            break                                                               
        except Exception:                                                       
            log.error("Error",exc_info=True)                                    
            break                                                               
                                                                                
def finished(name):                                                             
    return "Data was written to %s" % name                                      
                                                                                
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                      
    texter = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='|', skipinitialspace=True,             
                         quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, compression=enc, skiprows=[1],  
                         iterator=True, chunksize=1000)                         
                                                                                
    for i, df in enumerate(texter):                                             
        part_nm = i % mp.cpu_count()                                            
        name = os.path.join(temp_folder, 'part_%s' %  part_nm)                  
        queue.put((df, name))                                                   
                                                                                
    write_to_file()                                                             
                                                                                
    #for i in xrange(mp.cpu_count()):                                           
    #    p = mp.Process(target=write_to_file)                                   
    #    p.daemon = True                                                        
    #    workers.append(p)                                                      
                                                                                
    #for i in workers:                                                          
    #    i.start()                                                              
                                                                                
    #for i in workers:                                                          
    #    i.join()                                                               
                                                                                
    #log.info('The End')
```

Comment: well, each process will read in the entire file (and then write it out), that's exactly how you have coded it.

Comment: Can you please suggest how the task from queue can be processed only once?

Comment: why don't you just chunk process it: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk, multi-processing is generally not worth it unless you are doing a very expensive computation; for memory optimization it is useless.

Comment: Or, use the traditional `split` utility: http://linux.die.net/man/1/split  :)